# How to setup a voting gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, voting-system

How can I set a voting gem so it works as follows.

I have the following models
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :questions
    end

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :answers
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :question
end
```

using the Thumbs_up gem I can add

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voter
end

class Answer < ActiveRecord::Base
  acts_as_voteable
end
```

to add voting and

```
 validates_uniqueness_of :voteable_id, :scope => [:voteable_type, :voter_type, :voter_id]
```

to allows one vote per user, but that will not prevent uses from voting for all the answers. To go around this I am thinking of replacing link(votes) with radio button so user can only choose one answer. How can I set it up at the model(database level) so that when users updates their answer like in the example below

**For example:**

user can ask a question and add a list of options(answers) that friends can choose from.

```
which of the following programming language is easy to learn?
PHP
Java
Ruby
python
```

User can add as many option as they wish to the question. friends can only choose one answer but can update(change) to new answer, In which case the old answer get deleted when the new one is created.

**The output should be as follows:**

```
which of the following programming language is easy to learn?
Ruby(32 votes)
PHP(24 votes)
Java(13 votes)
python(9 votes)
```

One thing doesn't have to be the Thumbs_up any gem will gem do.

Comment: First hit off Google, is [acts_as_votable](https://github.com/ryanto/acts_as_votable), in the future, kindly show you've put some effort before wasting space here.

Comment: I have install acts_as_votable, but can't find in the docs how to set it up some it works like in the example.

Comment: @Francis Chibaye: To avoid looking like you haven't tried, it is good to add what you have tried, plus where specifically you are stuck, and best of all a little code to perhaps show your existing Rails model. Please edit details into the question. Not only will that stop readers thinking you are just chancing for some code (which unfortunately happens a lot on SO, hence the rude default assumption you see on this site), but actually it really helps someone to answer when they can base it off what you have already done.